# Tensorflow.tar.bz2 - How to install and import to Spyder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder, anaconda3

I downloaded the file `tensorflow-2.7.0-cpu_py310h6ecea76_0.tar.bz2`. Using Anaconda3 prompt I installed going to the directory and typing:

```
conda install tensorflow-2.7.0-cpu_py310h6ecea76_0.tar.bz2
```

However when I open the spyder and type: `import tensorflow` I receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\MFRANK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1/ipykernel_288/4294963926.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: Did you install Spyder using the Window standalone installer? If that is the case maybe this doc page could be useful: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to install TensorFlow in `Spyder IDE` after installing Anaconda.

1. Open the Anaconda command prompt
2. Create one virtual environment(tf)
3. Activate the same virtual environment(tf)
4. install tensorflow

> ```
> conda create --name tf python=3.9
> conda activate tf
> pip install tensorflow
> ```

Now, go to the Anaconda Navigator, open the `Spyder IDE` in the same(tf) virtual environment and try running your code.

(Try with below code to check if TensorFlow is installed in `Spyder IDE`)

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version)
```

You can also create a virtual environment directly through

> Anaconda Navigator - Environments - Create (+) - name(tf) - Select
> Python packages(3.9) - Create